# Android WebView Warnings

Tags: android, webview

I have a Fragment in a ViewPager which container one WebView to display offline content in HTML format. But i get some warnings and i don't know why. There is no problem in use but the warnings are annoying.

Here is the code:

```
// configure
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

// disable copy & paste
webView.setOnLongClickListener( new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});

// content
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html><head></head> ... </html>");
webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ViewCompat.setLayerType( webView, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null );
```

And here are the warnings:

> W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
>   W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
>   W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(630)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
>   W/cr.BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4441

Everything i want is to display some html offline with no JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It is working then it's fine. What the program is speaking in the first two warnings is that you tried to make a call and the program ignored because it was not necessary. Now is to know what this is called.

Comment: I'm also looking for more info on logcat warnings - I did find the following http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html and learned `W` signals a warning, followed by the app/package/plugin (`cr.B...` is chromium's BindingManager)